# Is there a way to trigger a CodePipeline stage if approval stage is declined?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

**Context:** I have a project where we use CodePipeline which updates the resources, methods and integrations of an API Gateway based on various blue/green flags set in DynamoDB. The integrations point to ECS stacks built in a different pipeline and are blue/green. The pipeline builds the configuration using terraform and templates. Once the templates are ready to be deployed there is an approval to verify the expected changes and deploy them if approved. We offer our customers a rollback period of 4 hours before we action a final approval stage to remove the old ECS stacks and API Gateway configs.

**Problem:** Is there a way I can programmatically roll back from this final stage? Is there a way in CodePipleine where I can add a condition-based stage or stages where one is triggered by approval, and removes the old stacks, and a different stage is triggered if I decline, which deploys the old config? I've looked at conditional stages but there doesn't seem to be a way to link them to approval steps.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that this is not something that can be done. So instead I have set up an EventBridge rule to check if the stage is declined and if so then trigger a new pipeline which will do the rollback for me.